# Hyper-simultaneous equation

Tags: polynomials

I am new here and of course I would like to be specific. I've found a general solution to the following system:

If $a$, $b$ and $c$ are given such that:
$$
x+y+z=a
$$
$$
x²+y²+z²=b
$$
$$
xⁿ+yⁿ+zⁿ=c
$$

Where $n=8$.

$x$, $y$ and $z$ could be devised using the method I have derived.

I just want to basically ask if this kind of thing is publishable. Thanks for your reply in anticipation.

Comment: Publishable it might as well be. Unless there is something super special about the method itself, I would not expect to publish in a journal, but rather on a conference paper. Note that MathOverflow (instead of MathStackExchange) might be more suitable for research-level mathematics.

Comment: Thanks for this sir. I will take that into account. But pls, how do I switch to mathoverflow?

Comment: [Here you go!](https://mathoverflow.net/)

Comment: Thanks sir! I really appreciate your response.

Comment: For me to not be too delusional about my method, please, looking at the system, can it be easily solved without much stress?

Answer (score 0):

I'm doubtful that this would be publishable unless the method is particularly neat or generalizable; it's not hard to find a method using matrices. Explicitly:

If a 3 by 3 matrix $A$ has eigenvalues $x, y, z$, then $A^8$ has eigenvalues $x^8, y^8, z^8$. Therefore, $tr(A^8) = x^8 + y^8 + z^8$. We can choose $A$ to be the companion matrix for a polynomial $x^3 - l x^2 - mx - n$. Then

$$x + y + z = tr(A) = l$$

$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = tr(A^2) = l^2 + 2m$$

$$x^8 + y^8 + z^8 = tr(A^8) = l^8 + 8 l^6 m + 20 l^4 m^2 + 16 l^2 m^3 + 2 m^4 + 8 l^5 n + 32 l^3 m n + 24 l m^2 n + 12 l^2 n^2 + 8 m n^2$$

So we set $l = a, m = \frac{b - a^2}{2}$, and solve the third equation to find $n$ (it's quadratic in $n$, so the solution won't be too difficult). Then $x, y, z$ are the eigenvalues of $A$, which can be determined by solving the above cubic.

Comment: To reduce the eighth powers to third powers only requires solving quadratic equation and i have confirmed that if the problem is reduced to that level, the new problem which involves linear, quadratic and cubic equations can be solved without much stress. If that is the case, do u still think I have something interesting at hand?

Answer (score 0):

See [Newton-Girard's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) for a more complete explanation of this technique.

Let:
$$
S_n =\sum_{k=1}^l x_i ^n
$$
$$
\sigma_1 = S_1
$$
$$
\sigma_2 = \sum_{i\neq j} x_i x_j
$$
$$
\sigma_3 = \sum_{i\neq j \neq k} x_i x_j x_k
$$

Then:
$$
S_2= \sigma_1^2-2\sigma_2
$$

$$
S_n = \sigma_1 S_{n-1}-\sigma_2S_{n-2}+\sigma_3 S_{n-3}-\cdots
$$

Thus in your case, we have: 
$$
a=\sigma_1
$$
$$
b= S_2
$$
$$
c = S_8
$$

Note that if we have $\sigma_1$, $\sigma_2$ and $\sigma_3$, then $x$, $y$ and $z$ are the roots of the equation:

$$
\lambda^3-\sigma_1 \lambda^2+\sigma_2 \lambda-\sigma_3=0
$$

Then $\sigma_2$ can be computed almost directly:

$$
\sigma_2 = \frac{a^2-b}{2}
$$

It remains to find $\sigma_3$, but it can be computed be recurring the formula until $S_8$ is written as a function of $\sigma_1$, $\sigma_2$ and $S_2$. It will likely yield an equation similar to the one @user44191 presented.

Basically, if you have an analytic method that does not incur into solving a third or higher degree polynomial, you might have something interesting in hand.

Comment: To reduce the eighth powers to third powers only requires quadrac